# I can't verify the contract on bscscan, I have installed Openzepplin. This is [HardHat] (Pictures add in)

Tags: solidity, contract-development, openzeppelin, hardhat, binance-smart-chain

Showing you first the deployed contract, smart contract, and then the error on the last picture. I have tried to deploy it with the URL but the problem remained. I myself know that there's an easy solution to this but as I'm a new blockchain developer is this a hard one for me. So any advice would I appreciate a lot. Will create a youtube channel to fix common issues on smart contracts and much more.

[image]

[image]
[image]

ParserError: Source "@openzeppelin/contracts/token/ERC20/ERC20.sol" not found: File import callback not supported
--> myc:4:1:
|
4 | import "@openzeppelin/contracts/token/ERC20/ERC20.sol"
| ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^

ParserError: Source "@openzeppelin/contracts/token/ERC20/extensions/ERC20Burnable.sol" not found: File import callback not supported
--> myc:5:1:
|
5 | import "@openzeppelin/contracts/token/ERC20/extensions/ERC20Burnable.sol"
| ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^

Answer (score 0):

Use this https://hardhat.org/plugins/nomiclabs-hardhat-etherscan.html
Get an API key from the explorer.

Bscscan cannot find the imports in your file.